# Reflecting Boundary conditions for advection-diffusion equations

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I am trying to model the dynamics of phytoplankton in a water column using one-dimensional advection-diffusion partial differential equations.

$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}= D\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x^2}-v\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}+rP, $$
where D is the diffusion coefficient and $v$ is advection. Both $D$ and $v$ are constant. 
 The topwater surface is at $x=0$ and the bottom is at $x=L$. The advection velocity is positive downward.   I am using the zero-flux boundary condition on the top surface, which is
$$ D\frac{dP(0)}{dx}-v P(0)=0. $$
My question is about the zero-flux boundary condition at the bottom of the water column. In most papers,  the zero-flux boundary condition at the bottom  is written also 
$$ D\frac{dP(L)}{dx} - vP(L)=0. $$
However, since phytoplankton can not escape the boundary (no-flux), so is not it should be
$$ D\frac{dP(L)}{dx} + vP(L)=0? $$
That is phytoplankton should bounce back at the bottom, so advection velocity will be in the upward direction so   + sign with advection term instead of negative at the bottom boundary at $x=L$? 
Any thoughts on it, please?

Comment: Please define P and $v$. If $v$ a constant ?

Comment: Yes, both $D$ and $v$ are constant.

Comment: On the one hand, you say that the advection velocity $v$ is constant. On the other hand, you say it is downward at the top edge and upward at the bottom edge. How are these two statements reconciled?

Answer (score 1):

The usual boundary condition
$$
D\frac{dP}{dx} -vP = 0
$$
seems correct regardless of whether one is considering $x=0$ or $x=L$. Note that the relative sign between the two terms has nothing to do with the orientation of the boundary surface. Instead, it encodes the relative orientation of the diffusion and advection effects, and that relative orientation is the same everywhere. Diffusion is always in direction of decreasing density $P$, and advection is always in direction of $v$.

For example, consider $P$ decreasing as $x$ approaches $L$. This means there will be diffusion towards the boundary. That has to be compensated by an advection velocity $v$ away from the boundary at $L$, which in your convention means negative $v$. Thus, $D \cdot dP/dx < 0$, and $vP<0$; to cancel, these have to subtracted from one another, corroborating the validity of the usual boundary condition.

Comment: Thank you so much and it makes much more sense. So just want to make sure I understood it correctly, advection velocity can not be constant than since it changes direction due to this relative orientation of diffusion and advection?

Comment: It seems to me that a solution with constant $v$ should be possible - it just implies that diffusion at one boundary is towards, at the other away from the boundary. I.e., $dP/dx$ has the same sign at the two boundaries.

Comment: Thanks again. I really appreciate your help.